# Issue with parsing Json data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to parse the below Json data:

```
{
    "userData": {
        "userId": 29922,
        "applicationId": 28,
        "siteId": 66
    },
    "verificationStatus": true
}
```

My Model Class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class LoginResponse {
  final UserData userData;
  final bool verificationStatus;

  LoginResponse({required this.userData, required this.verificationStatus});

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponse(
        verificationStatus: json['verificationStatus'] as bool,
        userData: UserData.fromJson(json['userData']) ,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userData'] = this.userData;
    data['verificationStatus'] = this.verificationStatus;
    return data;
  }
}

class UserData{
  final String userId;

  UserData({required this.userId});

  factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserData(
      userId: json['userId'] as String
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userId'] = this.userId;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
//loginResponse.body is the Json data
http.Response loginResponse = await postRequest();
LoginResponse response = jsonDecode(loginResponse.body);
print('status:>>$response.verificationStatus');
print('userId:>>$response.userData.userId');
```

But I am getting `Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'LoginResponse'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is here;

```dart
LoginResponse response = jsonDecode(loginResponse.body);
```

Should change like below;

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> parsedData = jsonDecode(loginResponse.body);
UserData userData = UserData.fromJson(parsedData);
```

And also, according to the provided JSON, the userId is not of type String; it is of type int. Therefore, you should change 'String' to 'int' in the UserData class.

Comment: how can I read the verificationstatus and userid from response?

Comment: where we are using the model class on this approach?

Comment: You can access the data only by following my instructions @SreejithSree

Comment: one more question, how we can print these values?

Comment: I tried like this `print('userid:>>$loginResponse.userData.userId'.toString());`

Comment: But I am getting `userid:>>Instance of 'LoginResponse'.userData.userId`

Comment: You should cover with '{}' like this: ```print('userid:>>${loginResponse.userData.userId}');```